# how to create scroll button dowm click on the list

Tags: list, button, scroll

The code appears to be related to supporting Ukraine and scrolling through a list of items. The CSS code in the blockquote formats the support button. The JavaScript code listens for a click event on the button and scrolls the list to the top or bottom depending on its current position.

```html
<aside>
  <div class="support-aside">
    <h2 class="support-title global-title">Support Ukraine
      <img src="./images/extra-block/tryzub.png" width="20" height="31" alt="tryzub"></h2>
      <ul class="support-list global-list"></ul>
      <button type="button" class="support-button global-button js-sup-btn">
        <svg class="support-svg">
          <use href="./images/extra-block/icons/arrow.svg#icon-arrow"></use>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </button>
  </div>
</aside>
```

```css
>! css
.support-button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-top: 13.1px;
  padding-bottom: 12.93px;
  padding-right: 10.17px;
  padding-left: 10.17px;
  background: var(--light-text-color);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.support-button.support-button-rotate {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1) rotate(180deg);
}
```

```js
const supportEl = document.querySelector('.list')
const supportBtn = document.querySelector('.js-sup-btn');
let isScrolledToEnd = false;

supportBtn.addEventListener('click', onScrollBtn)

function onScrollBtn() {
  if (isScrolledToEnd) {
    supportEl.scrollTop = 0;
    supportBtn.classList.remove('support-button-rotate');
  } else {
    supportEl.scrollTop = supportEl.scrollHeight;
    supportBtn.classList.add('support-button-rotate');
  }
  
  isScrolledToEnd = !isScrolledToEnd;
}
```